# IIS 6.0 loses MIME type after I set it

Tags: html, iis-6, video-streaming, mime-types

I'm hosting a few videos on an IIS server running version 6.0 and I have set my MIME types up properly (.mp4, video/mp4), however when I try and stream those videos it consistently tells me that the MIME types aren't supported.

Since I'm running IIS I don't think I need to worry about .htaccess but I could be wrong.

Any idea how I could be losing the MIME information?

Comment: How are you setting your MIME information?

Comment: I go under the properties of the IP address in IIS and add the MIME types there.

Comment: Have you tried setting it under the properties of the web site?  Are any other changes you're making getting saved?  It's possible you have [metabase corruption](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/a0ea8e51-fb2a-4e80-9d5a-7fe3ae246570.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: It seems that they are getting saved now, but the problem now lies in the HTML5 player I'm using. I'm not sure it supports the video formats I'm passing to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the MIME type directly under each individual site.

[Right Click] Site->Properties-> Http Headers-> Mime Types

Hope this helps